# I have little confusion in inheritance in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have class name Animal which consists of two methods, like...

```
Class Animal
{

protected function method1(){
    //some code
}

protected function method2(){
    //some code
}

}
```

Now I want to make two child classes which extends class Animal. One is cat 
and another is dog, like

```
Class Cat extends Animal
{
}
```

And,

```
Class Dog extends Animal
{
}
```

Now, what I want is that, child class Cat can access both the methods defined in class Animal, but class Dog can access method1, not method2. How can I set my access modifiers in class Animal, so that this logic can happen?

Comment: You should only have in the base class the actions that are common to every child. So, in this case, have `method()` be an `Animal` method, but `method1()` be only a `Cat` method.

Comment: Yep. If you find yourself with multiple sub-classes that need to share a behavior (like `Cat` and `Dog` have a `growFur()` method, but `Dolphin` does not) you'd want a trait.

Comment: If you're working on an existing codebase and just need to "disable" the method in a specific class (because refactoring is impractical), you can just redeclare `method1()` in `Dog` and leave it empty so that the parent function won't execute.

Comment: That's a really great point, @GentlemanMax.

Comment: Yep. If you find yourself with multiple sub-classes that need to share a behavior (like Cat and Dog have a growFur() method, but Dolphin does not) your abstraction is wrong.

Comment: I'd use the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that. It would violate the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). In OOP the `extends` keyword can be read as *"is special case of"*.

If you are too lazy to read,[here](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*tr7aEks-4fXenQ2Dyk0V2w.jpeg) is the short version.

Also, [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHBrDWIKW8Q) might be useful.